# My rain bird system has one zone that runs whenever any other zone is running

Tags: sprinkler-system

System is 10 years old and never did this before. Zone #6 runs whenever any of the other 7 zones are running even if each zone is turned on manually one by one. Zone #6 runs the same amount of time as each zone does and shuts off when the system or any zone set manually shuts off.

Comment: Easy theory is #6 valve is stuck open because of debris or failure.  But in most systems it would then run all the time, 24x7.  Do you have a master valve or a pump that would prevent that, and make a stuck-open zone run only when something else is on?

Comment: By "manually" do you mean at the computer or using the knob on the valve itself in the pit?  If you mean at the computer, what happens if you open a different zone using the knob on the valve?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two possible explanations:

1. If your system has a master valve or a pump, then the most likely explanation is that your #6 zone valve is stuck open.  When any other zone runs, the master valve or pump activates and zone #6 gets fed in addition to the desired zone.   You can diagnose a stuck or broken solenoid/actuator by removing it from the valve.  IF that fixes the problem, replace the solenoid. .  If not you probably have debris in the valve or it's broken.  Look for the make and model then look on youtube or the manufacturer's web site how to clean it or replace parts.  It's easy but not obvious.  To replace parts it's often easier/cheaper to buy a new valve and remove the needed parts from it.
2. If your system does not have a master valve or pump, it must be that zone #6 is receiving power whenever any other zone is.  The only explanation I can think of is a defective controller.  You can confirm this by disconnecting the wire at the controller end and using a meter.   If that's the problem, replace the controller.  Some controllers are modular, you can replace the circuit board without changing the enclosure, PSU and terminal block.   That's a one-minute job (not including reprogramming).

Answer (score 0):

### Electrical:

Assuming it is not electrical-- easy to check, just disconect the wires.

### Mechanical:

Possible causes are the spring inside the actuator is Brocken or weak and needs replacement.

Another possible cause is the rubber membrane (the large disk) has a leak. Replace.

Comment: Great responses. Debris must have been holding #6 open because it started working after re-testing a number of times. I have a pump that draws water from a lake so that was most likely where the debris came from. Thanks to all.